# How to resolve error: "Recurring contribution, but no database id"?

Tags: civimember, payment-processor, recurring-contributions

When processing a new recurring *membership*, with the *"Please renew my membership automatically"* option enabled, we get the following error:

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
>
> Recurring contribution, but no database id

What can we do to troubleshoot/resolve this issue?

## Temporary fix

As a temporary fix, we set the *Membership Type Auto-renew Option* value to *No auto-renew option*. Now, we can process memberships, but those memberships can not auto-renew.

We would like for members to have the option to auto-renew their membership.

## Environment

- Drupal 7.x
- CiviCRM 4.7.x
- MySQL

Comment: Please post your CMS and CiviCRM version?

Comment: Thanks cor the clarifying question @JonG. I have added details about our server environment to the question.

Comment: I have also added clarifications regarding the recurring membership option.

Answer (score 2):

I am also experiencing this issue and have raised an issue in JIRA - https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18389.  You can fix this by upgrading to CiviCRM 4.7.9 or higher.

Comment: I know. However I don't have enough reputation to add it as a comment which is what it should be - and I think it's valuable information to assist the original poster in resolving the issue - as is the other "answer" on the page which you have flagged similarly.

Answer (score -1):

I was just testing my Membership Contributions pages in the PayPal Sandbox to see what does happen when a renewal goes through (I was expecting a receipt sent from CiviCRM), however I'm seeing the same error that Mr. Oxley is seeing.

This on :
Joomla 3.5.0
CiviCRM 4.7.4
MySql 5.5.45
PHP 5.5.31

Here's the relevant log entries:

```
Apr 04 05:42:23  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => Recurring contribution, but no database id
    [code] =>
)


Apr 04 05:42:23  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(366): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)

1 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalImpl.php(904): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Recurring contribution, but no database id")

2 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment.php(978): CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalImpl->doTransferCheckout((Array:59), "contribute")

3 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalImpl.php(457): CRM_Core_Payment->doPayment((Array:59), "contribute")

4 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(1575): CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalImpl->doPayment((Array:59), "contribute")

5 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(1361): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->postProcessMembership((Array:54), "347", Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), (Array:50), (Array:0), (Array:0), (Array:13), (Array:1), TRUE, NULL, FALSE, "2", (Array:0), 0, TRUE)

6 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(2266): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->processMembership((Array:54), "347", (Array:0), (Array:0), (Array:50), (Array:0), 0)

7 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(2140): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->doMembershipProcessing("347", (Array:53), (Array:50), 0)

8 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(594): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->processFormSubmission("347")

9 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(423): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->postProcess()

10 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(160): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()

11 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), "next", "Next")

12 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), "next")

13 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), "next")

14 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")

15 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)

16 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))

17 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))

18 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(116): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))

19 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke()

20 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(405): require_once("/home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")

21 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(380): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")

22 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php(98): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")

23 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php(152): JApplicationAdministrator->dispatch()

24 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(257): JApplicationAdministrator->doExecute()

25 /home/nwtaadmin/public_html/administrator/index.php(51): JApplicationCms->execute()

26 {main}
```